# where to find bodyfat dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataset, package

I'm trying tutorial from [R and Data Mining: Examples and Case Studies](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Zhao_R_and_data_mining.pdf) 
Yanchang Zhao, April 26, 2013. I tried to access bodyfat dataset from mboost package but I'm getting following error:

> data("bodyfat", package = "mboost")

Warning message:
In data("bodyfat", package = "mboost") : data set ‘bodyfat’ not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mboost/vignettes/mboost_tutorial.pdf suggests it is here:

`data("bodyfat", package = "TH.data")`

Comment: Correct; It was used for CRAN policy reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sos`

```
library(sos)

???'bodyfat'
```

Comment: Good solution, always forget about `sos`. Not sure why this was down-voted.

Answer (score 2):

Bodyfat dataset is no longer available in mboost package.
The dataset is provided in package TH.data.
Install "TH.data" package to access bodyfat dataset.

```
install.packages("TH.data")
```

`data("bodyfat", package="TH.data")`

```
str(bodyfat)
```